# Is javamail a less secure application?

Tags: java, email, gmail, jakarta-mail, email-client

I was just working on an email program that read emails from [Gmail](http://mail.google.com) and does further processing. Initially using the code provide in SO(link provided below) I was getting an exception which says that "My access has been blocked and I need to login via web browser".

On the same time I saw an email in inbox (to which I am trying to connect) which says that "**Google Account: sign-in attempt blocked**" and I need to disable modern security from following link "https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps".

I tried to disable and I was succesfully connected.

So does it means that `Javamail` is a less secure application? Or there are ways by which I can still connect without disabling the option?

Thanks in advance.
Garry

[[Code I used:]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137405/retrieving-all-unread-emails-using-javamail)

Comment: JavaMail is an API, not an application. The question doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 4):

It's really hard to tell because Google isn't saying exactly what "modern security standards" an app needs to implement to be "more secure", but I suspect they're referring to [this blog entry where they talk about OAuth2](http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/new-security-measures-will-affect-older.html).  JavaMail is capable of using the [OAuth2 authentication mechanism](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2), which I guess makes JavaMail a "more secure" application.

Comment: I'm going to verify your suggestion, thanks. I use the following code to reproduce this problem: Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
            Store store = session.getStore();
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com", 993, "*******@gmail.com", "**password**");