# Android gives "javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException" while sending email in activity

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I am using javax mail to send mail from my activity. Here is my properties

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    properties.setProperty("mail.host", mailhost);
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", "995");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");
```

While using this settings javax gives that error "javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException".

And i must turn off the google security from this [link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps)!

But i dont want to turn off security service. Is there any way to use? I think problem is my properties, but i cant figure out.

Comment: maybe you need username and password to access your smtp server

Comment: is it helpful ! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18778240/solve-error-javax-mail-authenticationfailedexception

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Of course i use username and password. This code is only properties part.

Comment: @RanjitPati 587 does not work.

Answer (score 1):

For sending email using `JavaMail` you'll need to configure your Gmail account to enable less secure apps, or you'll need to use [OAuth2 authentication](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2) (which is somewhat more complex).

Might be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25156129/is-javamail-a-less-secure-application) also useful for you .For tutorial [visit](http://beansgocrazy.blogspot.com.au/2012/08/android-app-to-send-g-mails-through.html).or search *java send email using oauth* in google :)