# Receive/Read emails in android

Tags: java, android, email

I am new to android.I want to build an app to receive & read emails from my own app.I prepared my code with help of these links & some blogs.

[Retrieving all unread emails using javamail with POP3 protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137405/retrieving-all-unread-emails-using-javamail?rq=1)

https://buddhimawijeweera.wordpress.com/2011/02/09/sendreceiveemailsjava/

https://metoojava.wordpress.com/2010/03/21/java-code-to-receive-mail-using-javamailapi/

I have been working nearly for two weeks,but still app doesn't display the received emails.Please help me to find errors.Or else do you know a code to connect Gmail app with my app to receive emails ? Your any help for the app is greatly appreciated.

MailReaderActivity.java (Main Activity)

```
public class MailReaderActivity extends Activity{

    Folder inbox;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);


    }

    public MailReaderActivity(){

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        try {

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
            Store store;
            store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect("imap.gmail.com","<user@gmail.com>","<password>");

            inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            System.out.println("No of Unread Messages : " + inbox.getUnreadMessageCount());

            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

            Message messages[] = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));

            FetchProfile fp = new FetchProfile();
            fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.ENVELOPE);
            fp.add(FetchProfile.Item.CONTENT_INFO);
            inbox.fetch(messages, fp);

            try {
                printAllMessages(messages);
                inbox.close(true);
                store.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("Exception arise at the time of read mail");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(2);
        }
    }


    public void printAllMessages(Message[] msgs) throws Exception
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("MESSAGE #" + (i + 1) + ":");
            printEnvelope(msgs[i]);
        }
    }
    public void printEnvelope(Message message) throws Exception
    {
        Address[] a;
        // FROM
        if ((a = message.getFrom()) != null)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("FROM: " + a[j].toString());
            }
        }
        // TO
        if ((a = message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO)) != null)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            {
                System.out.println("TO: " + a[j].toString());
            }
        }
        String subject = message.getSubject();
        Date receivedDate = message.getReceivedDate();
        String content = message.getContent().toString();
        System.out.println("Subject : " + subject);
        System.out.println("Received Date : " + receivedDate.toString());
        System.out.println("Content : " + content);
        getContent(message);
    }

    public void getContent(Message msg)
    {
        try
        {
            String contentType = msg.getContentType();
            System.out.println("Content Type : " + contentType);
            Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
            int count = mp.getCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                dumpPart(mp.getBodyPart(i));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception arise at get Content");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void dumpPart(Part p) throws Exception
    {
        // Dump input stream ..
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        // If "is" is not already buffered, wrap a BufferedInputStream
        // around it.
        if (!(is instanceof BufferedInputStream))
        {
            is = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        }
        int c;
        System.out.println("Message : ");
        while ((c = is.read()) != -1)
        {
            System.out.write(c);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new MailReaderActivity();
    }
}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MailReaderActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

```
Logcat

 //01-19 13:09:00.554    8487-8487/com.example.dell.frfr E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
01-19 13:09:00.812    8487-8487/com.example.dell.frfr E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dell.frfr/com.example.dell.frfr.MailReaderActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1128)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:289)
            at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:105)
            at java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:90)
            at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:321)
            at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
            at com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:116)
            at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:115)
            at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.newIMAPProtocol(IMAPStore.java:685)
            at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:636)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
            at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
            at com.example.dell.frfr.MailReaderActivity.<init>(MailReaderActivity.java:53)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5370)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
//
```

Comment: could you please post ur logcat?

Comment: StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);  <-- These should be called before calling the content of your constructor. Try adding the content of the constructor after above two lines in onCreate() method

Comment: Thank you for your help .The exception "NetworkOnMailThread" is not displayed now.But still messages are not displayed.
The debug output is like below;
 DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "imap.gmail.com", port 993, isSSL true

We suppose that the problem is in connecting to the account.Is there any change we have to do in the code for that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you have already fixed this error or not, but it may help people with a similar issue if i still answer it.

In your LogCat. It says `Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`
Android by default will not let any networking on the same thread as the rest of the application. So, to fix this we just have to simply create a new thread to run it in.

Replace:

```java
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        new MailReaderActivity();
    }
```

with this:

```java
public static void main(String args[])
{
  Thread thread = new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          new MailReaderActivity();
      }
  };

  thread.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should execute network threads asynchronously using `AsyncTask`. For further information read [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask).