# Is any plugin for it that can manage mails downloading from yahoo,gmail,outlook etc

Tags: grails

i am looking grails plugin or api in java which can handle downloading mails.In grails is any plugin or api which can handle all downloading from mail accounts.

And provide some functionality like

download latest mail.
old mails
thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are no plugins that exist for fetching e-mails in Grails, however, Java does supply the fantastic [JavaMail API](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home#API_Documentation). There are [lots](http://alvinalexander.com/java/javamail-pop-pop3-reader-email-inbox-example), and [lots](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/06/reading-email-using-javamail-api-example.html), and [lots](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/index.htm) of tutorials/examples about using it.

There is also quite a few [working example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137405/retrieving-all-unread-emails-using-javamail)s on here on stackoverflow.