# Accessing emails from gmail using IMAP in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to access emails from Gmail accounts through IMAP with the help of the JavaMail API.

I am able to access the Inbox folder of both email accounts. But i want to view only not read message, and the number of it, it is possible ? 
Thank you in advance.

Here is the code:

```
  // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
  Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
  System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

  for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
     Message message = messages[i];
     System.out.println("---------------------------------");
     System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
     System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
     System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
     System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());

  }
```

Comment: ***and what does `messages.length` give you ?***

Comment: give me all the message ! and i want only not read message !!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Retrieving all unread emails using javamail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13137405/retrieving-all-unread-emails-using-javamail)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line will give unread messages count

```
System.out.println("unread count - " + folder.getUnreadMessageCount());
```

and the following line will give you all unread messages

```
Message[] unreadMessages = folder.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
```

hope this helps you...